# First order logic,Step in Derivation of Non standard real numbers

Tags: propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, nonstandard-analysis

This is from first order logic, specifically a section detailing the construction of the non standard real numbers, after Los' theorem
And we have that:\
\
Let $L = \{+, ×, <, 0, 1\}$ be the language we usually use for this structure.
Let $M = R$. Let I be the usual interpretation of L in R. Let $M = (M, I)$.

For each $r \in R$, let $c_r$ be a new constant symbol. Do this in such a way that, for all $r, r' \in R, c_r \neq c_r' $ and $c_r \notin \{ 0, 1\}$.

Let $L_R = L \cup \{c_r : r \in R\}.$
Let $I_R$ be the natural interpretation of $L_R$ in R (so $I_R$ agrees with I on L and, for each r $\in$ R, $I_R(c_r) = r$). Let $M_R = (R, I_R)$.
Finally, let $b \notin \{c_r : r \in R\} \cup {0, 1}$ be a new constant symbol and let
$L_b = L_R \cup \{b\}$. For each $a \in R$, let $I_a$ be the interpretation of $L_b$ in R
which agrees with $I_R$ on $L_R$ and is such that $I_a(b) = a$. For each $a \in R$, let $M_a = (R, Ia)$.
Let $\Sigma$ be the set of all $L_b$-sentences $\sigma$ such that
\begin{eqnarray}
(i) & \sigma \in L_R \wedge M_R \models \sigma \quad or \nonumber \\
(ii)& \sigma \in \{(< (0, b)) \wedge (< (b, c_r)) : r \in \{ \frac{1}{n}: n \in N\}\}.
\end{eqnarray}
Let $\Sigma ' \subseteq \Sigma$ be finite. Let $a(\Sigma ')$ be r where r is the smallest positive
real number such that $c_r$ appears in at least one of the sentences in $\Sigma '$, if such exists. Otherwise, let $a(\Sigma '
) = 2$ (or any other real number you like).

Show that $M_{a(\Sigma ')} \models \Sigma '$

My approach was to assume that $M_{a\Sigma '} (\neg\models) \Sigma '$
and then try to show that there does exist a satisfiable $\sigma \in \Sigma '$ and then that $\sigma$ is satisfiable and hence $M_{a(\Sigma ')}\models \Sigma '$ But I'm uncertain on whether this is the best approach and what forces the $\sigma$ to be satisfiable.``

Comment: Yes, that's correct @HenningMakholm

Comment: From the notes I'm using it is definitely the smallest positive real number @HenningMakholm

Comment: x @Und: The notes may be somewhat sloppily prepared, then. They seem like they're a mixture of two related but _different_ constructions of a non-standard model, and the pieces don't quite fit together. (I've updated my answer with a discussion of how to salvage the construction).

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is overcomplicating the task at hand. Instead, just show that $M_{a(\Sigma')}\vDash \sigma'$ for each $\sigma' \in\Sigma'$ separately.

Such a $\sigma'$ will either be something that is true in $M_R$, and therefore also in every $M_a$, or it will assert that $0<b<c_r$ for some $c_r$ where the interpretation of $c_r$ is by construction larger than $a(\Sigma')$.

---

Actually there's something fishy about the construction which I think *looks like* typos that are easily fixed but it's not quite clear to me which direction they're supposed to be fixed in.

Your $\Sigma$ adds new axioms $0<b<r$ for some set of $r$s -- which looks like $b$ is supposed to become an infinitesimal. But what you have written is actually only that $b$ must be squeezed between $0$ and $r$ for every $r\in \mathbb N$, which is easily achievable without any nonstandard elements -- as written, $M_{1/2}$ will satisfy all of $\Sigma$.

What must be meant is *either* to aim for $b$ being *infinitesimal* and add axioms
$$ 0<b \land b<c_r \qquad\text{for every }r\in(0,\infty) $$
*or* to aim for $b$ being *infinite* and add axioms
$$ c_r <b \qquad\text{for every }r\in\mathbb N $$

The definition of $a(\Sigma')$ that works in each of those cases will be either (say) half of the *smallest* positive $r$ such that $\Sigma'$ mentions $c_r$, or (say) one plus the *largest* $r$ such that $\Sigma'$ mentions $c_r$.

Comment: The aim is to add infinitesimals, the mistake was on my part, the formal notation we use, that is \begin{eqnarray}
(ii)& \sigma \in \{(< (0, b)) \wedge (< (b, c_r)) : r \in \{ n: n \in N\}\}.\nonumber\\
&\textrm{Translates to}\nonumber\\
&\sigma \in \{ 0< b < c_r : r \in \{ n: n \in N\}\}.\nonumber\\
&\textrm{Where N is the natural numbers}\nonumber
\end{eqnarray}
Hope that clears it up for you

Comment: @UndergradLogic: That still doesn't give you an infinitesimal, just some number between $0$ and $1$. Did you perhaps mean to write $\{\frac1n:n\in\mathbb N\}$ instead?

Comment: Yes! You're totally correct! Sorry about that

Comment: @UndergradLogic: Then you just need to fix your definition of $a(\Sigma')$ somehow, because as it stands it won't work. For example take $\Sigma'$ to be the 1-element set $\{0<b<c_1\}$, you would then have $a(\Sigma')=1$ and the claim would be that $$M_1\vDash 0<b<c_1 $$ which is false because $M_1$ maps both of $b$ and $c_1$ to $1$, which is not less than itself!

Comment: Isn't that particular case covered by the face that b cannot be 0 or 1 by definition? And for everything else the definition of $a(\Sigma ')$ is fine?

Comment: @UndergradLogic: That's a red herring. The _symbol_ $b$ is different from the _symbols_ $0$ and $1$, but nothing prevents an _interpretation_ from mapping the two different _symbols_ $1$ and $b$ to the same _element_ of the structure.

Comment: And the problem holds in general. If there is any $c_r$ in $\Sigma'$, then the value of $a(\Sigma')$ as currently defined will be one particular $r$ such that $c_r$ appears in $\Sigma'$. And the only way a $c_r$ can appear in $\Sigma'$ is in one of the axioms $0<b<c_r$, which means that $M_r\vDash\Sigma'$ can only be true if that particular $0<b<c_r$ is satisfied by $M_r$. But _by definition_ $M_r$ maps $b$ and $c_r$ to the same element, so $M_c\not\vDash b<c_r$ always. Therefore, in order for things to work, $a(\Sigma')$ needs to be _different from_ (and smaller than) each of the ...

Comment: ... positive $r$ for which $c_r$ appears in $\Sigma'$.